# How do you provide a magnified view within layout view?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

[image: Here's what my map looks like now.]

I want to label each land parcel and realize some groups of parcels are too small and close together to label effectively. Therefore, I want to create a magnified view to include on the sheet for this region.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: did you see this link:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/100155/arcgis-label-zoom-visibility

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another data frame to your layout.  In that new data frame you copy all the layers you want to display in your inset.  The easiest way to do this is to just drag and drop from your main data frame into the new one.  This will *copy* them to the new data frame.

1. Insert Data Frame
   [image]
2. Copy layers to new Data Frame
   [image]

Once you have your new data frame and layers, position the new data frame inset where you want it on the page, set your data frame properties background colour to white (or another colour if preferred) to block any data from the main data frame from showing through it), and zoom into your area of interest.

Once this is done you can add "Extent Indicators" to show where your inset relates to on your main data frame.  Extent Indicators are added via the main data frame's Properties dialog, on the Extent Indicators tab.

3. Position Inset, add Extent Indicators
   [image]